# How to solve error performing FM Demodulation in octave?

Tags: audio, signals, octave, telecommunication

I am trying to demodulate a modulated FM Signal. As you can see in the code below I use fmmod to modulate the FM signal, however when I use fmdemod or ademodce then neither returns anything similar to the original signal. For fmdemod I believe it is that you can not enter freqdev as in fmmod, so it does not perform the reverse. With ademodce I have no idea why that is not working. Is there any other Octave function I can use to attain the original signal again or how do I use either one of these two correctly to do it?

See example code below:

```
    [sound2,fs]=audioread('sound2.wav');
    
    fc=7500;
    freqdev=100;
    dt=1/fs;
    len=length(sound2)*dt;
    
    t=0:dt:len;
    t=t(1:end-1);
    t1=t(1:end-1);
    
    FMmod=fmmod(sound2.',fc,fs,freqdev);
    FMDemod=ademodce(FMmod,fs,"fm",freqdev); %Or fmdemod(FMmod.',fc,fs) Neither is working.
    
    sound(sound2,fs)
    sound(FMDemod,fs)
    
    
    subplot(2,2,1),plot(t,sound2),title('Original Sound');
    
    subplot(2,2,2),plot(t,FMmod,'r'),title('FM Modulated');
    
    subplot(2,2,3),plot(t,FMDemod,'g'),title('FM De-Modulated');
    
    subplot(2,2,4),plot(t,FMmod-sound2.'), title('Carrier Signal');
```

Comment: I hate to say it, but for all my love for the Octave project, all the stuff you've identified seem to be bugs in the communications package. If you look at the package's [source repository](https://sourceforge.net/p/octave/communications/ci/default/tree/inst/), it becomes clear that these particular functions at least, have not received much love since 2007 ... I do not know much about FM modulation/demodulation, but having said that, if you look at the source code involved, aside from the correctness of the maths involved, these seem like fairly simple implementations.

Comment: I would strongly encourage you to raise all these as bugs in the octave bug tracker. The original author's name is also mentioned in these files, perhaps you can encourage him (or urge the Octave people to do so in your bug report) to return and pour some love into these functions again (with the possible advantage of an extra 13 years of expertise at this point!). If you know and understand the math behind modulation / demodulation, you might even decide to edit those functions and correct any inconsistencies (like I said, the code itself seems very simple).

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I will unfortunately not have the time right now for this project to do that, however in the next few weeks I will be studying FM Modulation and once I have a better understanding of it, I may be able to code it correctly. I will update here and on the octave bug tracker accordingly.